# React app freezing in chrome after several hours of being open

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, debugging, websocket

Not a specific programming query but more in relation to a javascript app as a whole having a general problem and looking for any possible solutions to debug it.

I'm using React and have a single page app which is receiving streaming data from a websocket about 40 times a second. The user display is updated a similar amount of times each second to show the updates.

The problem I'm having is that after running the page for more than 12 hours not only google chrome, but all of other applications start to freeze momentarily. If I start trying to do too much with the other applications, sometimes all windows on chrome will turn black and it can freeze for up to 30 seconds.  The more processing/memory used by other applications and the more versions of the react app I have open, the faster the freezing starts, but in any case only starts after a few hours.

The only fix is currently to restart the whole of windows because even after closing chrome the problem persists.

I've tried using google chrome profiling to inspect the heap type to see a memory leak but the memory size is the same as when I first launched the app.
I've tried reinstalling chrome but this didn't fix the problem either.
I read somewhere online that freezing like this could be due to too much garbage collection? But what would be triggering this to happen in excess? And I don't understand why that would persist after I close google chrome.

A possible solution would be to build in an auto-refresher to refresh the page every hour once the user has been idle for at least 5 minute, but this seems a bit overkill if its a problem which can be solved.

Any tips/advice for debugging this kind of issue or obvious places I should search for a solution? as its very much un-shipable in its current state

Comment: So you'd still send streaming data even when the user is idle? Seems like a waste of data and energy. Why not stop that when the user is idle and continue when the user is active again? Might solve your problem.

Comment: Good suggestion. I should have said that idle would mean a user is keeping an eye on it, but could sneak in a refresh if it wasn't during a very busy period for them.

Comment: You are not alone one this one. I thought I had my machine all spec'ed up, but yes after running React-Web with npm. I started to see the same problem. 
as you mentioned. @putvande what do you mean, is this is something to change in React or chrome?

Comment: I am having this issue as well. how were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to one of the two following things on windows 10. I performed both and one of them has caused the freezing to stop:
1) In control Panel -> Power options -> additional power settings -> change plan settings -> change advanced settings-> change the hard-drive sleep option to never or 0 
2) Updated chip-set drivers from the motherboard manufacturers website.

Comment: lol i have been having the exact same problem on a mac. but i'm talking about a web app intended for clients - so im not gonna tell them to update stuff or change configurations on their machine. I wonder if there is something that can be done programmatically to fix this issue